# Как не включать в массив элемент по условию?

Tags: php, yii

Доброго всем дня!

Есть такой вопрос: можно ли не включить в массив какой-либо элемент, используя `if()/else()`?

Пример:

```
 $array = [
'something'=>false,
'var'=>true,
'innerArrays'=>[
['title'=>1],
['title'=>2],
['title'=>3]
]
];
```

В данном массиве нужно по условию выводить массив `['title'=>2]` или не выводить. Вопрос, как это сделать? Какое условие, совершенно не важно. Например, `if($userName=='admin');`.

Заранее благодарю за любую помощь.

P.S.На всякий случай поясню: это утрированный пример вывода колонок по условию в gridview в yii2. Так что если найдется решение, то его будут активно применять для отображения, например, разных колонок для разных ролей пользователей. Утрированный пример привел специально, т.к. вопрос скорее языка, нежели фреймворка.
Пример из фреймворка (из документации):

```
echo GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
        // A simple column defined by the data contained in $dataProvider.
        // Data from the model's column1 will be used.
        'id',
        'username',
        // More complex one.
        [
            'class' => 'yii\grid\DataColumn', // can be omitted, default
            'value' => function ($data) {
                return $data->name; //$data['name'] for array data, e.g. using SqlDataProvider.
            },
        ],
    ],
]);
```

Меня интересует вывод массивов внутри массива columns. Их может быть довольно много, и не все из них нужно показывать определенным ролям пользователей.

**UPD: если вдруг кому пригодится.**
**Решение для gridview** если мы например хотим показывать колонку username и следующую после нее только админу:

```
if(Yii::$app->user->identity->username!=='admin'){ //Условие можно поставить любое
$badkey = [1,2] //тут перечисляются индексы, которые не хотим показывать.
}
//Массив с колонками выносим в переменную для удобства
$columns = [
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
            'id',
            'username',
            [
                'class' => 'yii\grid\DataColumn', 
                'value' => function ($data) {
                    return $data->name; 
                },
            ],
        ];
//Перебираем массив с колонками, как показал товарищ Get и ищем в массиве ненужные //нам индексы. Если нашли - удаляем этот элемент из массива с помощью unset()
foreach($columns as $key=>$value){
        if(in_array($key,$badkey)){
            unset($columns[$key]);
        }
    }

//После этого выводим сам грид с подготовленным массивом колонок.
echo GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'columns' => $columns
    ]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$badkey = ''; // индексы исключаемых элементов отсутствуют
If ($username=='admin'){
  $badkey = 1; // индекс исключаемых элементов
}
foreach ($array as $key=>$arr) {
If (($key!=$badkey))
  var_dump($arr);
}
```

Comment: А если массив будет таким? 
`$array = [
'something'=>false,
'var'=>true,
'innerArrays'=>[
['title'=>1],
['title'=>2],
['title'=>3]
]
];`
И исключить по прежнему нужно только ['title'=>2]

Comment: @makbeth, а если в массиве будет несколько элементов, содержащих данный ключ - их все надо будет игнорировать?

Comment: ок, пойдем по порядку

    $badkey = ''; 
    ...
    If (($key!=$badkey))

угадайте, что произойдет на нулевом элементе

> If

не надо писать управляющие конструкции и константы null/false/true не в нижнем кейсе, не надо опускать пробелы по сторонам от операторов сравнения, не надо использовать нестрогое сравнение

    var_dump($arr);

это явно не то, что хотел автор

    (($key!=$badkey))

зачем две пары скобок?

    $badkey = 1;

Лучше сразу задавать массив ключей.

Comment: На всякий случай поясню: это утрированный пример вывода колонок по условию в gridview в yii2. Так что если найдется решение, то его будут активно применять для отображения, например, разных колонок для разных ролей пользователей. Утрированный пример привел специально, т.к. вопрос скорее языка, нежели фреймворка.

Comment: Подправил вопрос и сделал его более развернутым

Comment: @Etki, 

с первым замечанием согласен, надо заменить != в условии на !==

второе - автор просил выводить или не выводить элемент. По результату var_dump элемент выводится или не выводится. Считаю, что дальнейшую логику автор должен реализовать самостоятельно.

третье - лишнюю пару скобок просто забыл удалить. Изначально писал if с двумя условиями, объединенными &&.

четвертое - согласен, что лучше сразу задавать массив, но в вопросе автора стояла задача исключить только один элемент, поэтому сделал строкой.

Comment: @makbeth, чем вас не устраивает мой ответ? Что-то не понятно? Объясняю, надо создать список элементов, которые вы хотите выводить или не выводить. При переборе массива, внутри цикла, проверять не входит ли текущий индекс элемента в указанный выше список элементов и, соответственно, показывать или не показывать текущий элемент.

Comment: @makbeth, для перебора приведенного вами в комментариях массива поставьте в foreach не $array, а $array[innerArrays].

Comment: Тут вопрос с выводом. На самом деле мне не вывод нужен... Скорее нужно убрать элемент из массива по условию. Только что-то не пойму как реализовать...

Comment: Циклом пробегаетесь по массиву. Внутри цикла делаете проверку входит ли текущий элемент в массив элементов, которые надо показывать. Если входит - показывайте. Про убрать элемент из массива - смотрите функцию unset() http://oooportal.ru/?cat=article&id=665

Если массив состоит из других массивов, то делаете вложенные циклы.

Comment: @Get, вы о чем? Какие вложенные циклы? У меня может быть в массиве массив, в нем еще один и так далее до миллиардного уровня. Мне миллиард вложенных циклов делать?

Здесь рекурсией легко все делать, если надо удалить - удаляем, если надо не выводить, тогда просто копируем массив в момент прохода элементов

Можно и без рекурсии, через ваши вложенные циклы, но это может сделать только тот, кто в рекурсии хорошо разбирается. Чтобы разложить ее в цикл и эмулировать стеки. В питоне это полезно, т.к. стек ограничен, но здесь-то я думаю проблем быть не должно.

Так что долой циклы, даешь рекурсию )

Answer (score 0):

```
$columns1 = [
  [col1],
  [col2],
];
$column2 = [
  [col4],
  [col5]
];

if (условие) {
  $colums = array_merge($column1, $column2);
} else {
  $colums = array_merge($column1, [col3] $column2);
}
```